# EditText background created programmatically doesn't increase in size with the edit text

Tags: android

I have created an edit text background with a colored stroke. It appears to work fine, but when the user adds more than one line of text into the edit text the et is growing in size but when the user clicks out of the edit text the background stays the original size and doesn't expand with it. Would anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
   gradientBackground = GradientDrawable()
   gradientBackground.apply {
        GradientDrawable()
        shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
        setStroke(4, colour ?: ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
        cornerRadius = 90f
    }

   etCheckInChallenges1New.background = gradientBackground
```

[image]

EDIT: From further testing when making the drawable via xml and setting it as the background either in the xml or programmatically it works as desired i.e. the background expands with the edittext multiline. The problem occurs when making the background shape programatically.....

Comment: I suggest creating the drawable from XML and then comparing that (in a debugger) to the one created programmatically. That might show you what the difference is.

Comment: i will suggest youuse 9 patch image for background of any view that is to be of variable size it would automatically adjust its background as text in view goes to next line

Comment: Do you absolutely have to set background programmatically? Why nit just create create xml shape and use that, since its working? The above background can easily be created through xml

Comment: Cause there is a list of 40 colours relating to ui objects. I dont want to create 40 backgrounds each with a different stroke colour

Comment: you can use tint option to get desired color and make just one ui object

Answer (score 0):

I have tried. There's no problem in your code and works fine:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />
```

and setting background:

```
val gradientBackground = GradientDrawable().apply {
    shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
    setStroke(4, Color.RED)
    cornerRadius = 90f
}
binding.et.background = gradientBackground
```

[image: single line]
[image: multiple line]

Answer (score -1):

you need to make its height wrap_content to make it goes to next line as many times as user needs.

```
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```